# Is Trello accessible to a blind user via screenreading software?

Tags: trello, accessibility

My group is considering using Trello for projects, but anything we use must be accessible to blind team members who use screenreading software. Does Trello work well with JAWS, VoiceOver, or anything similar?

Comment: Could you not experiment yourself, and report backnhere, as it sounds like you have accee to the technology, and Trello is obviously free and simple to set up an account?

Comment: Ok, it's been 8 years, 4 months. I still have no idea what accessibility work has been done on Trello & can't seem to find good references for accommodation or adaption for people with disabilities (permanent, temporary or situational). Most I've been able to find is this article about support for those who are color blind https://www.invisionapp.com/inside-design/color-accessibility-product-design/

Answer (score 1):

We don't have any reports of Trello working or not working with screen reader software.

Answer (score 1):

Trello is not accessible.

- Tab moves into a column and open the column to edit the name
- up and down navigates the right-column and activity stream
- If you know about the keyboard short cuts (https://trello.com/shortcuts), they successfully navigate, but only the input key is verbalized - the content of the element is ignored.

This makes Trello unusable with NVDA.

I tested this with NVDA 2012.3.1 on Windows 7 on May 17, 2013 (I couldn't find version info on Trello)

Answer (score 0):

From Rich Armstrong's response, my guess is that Trello will NOT work! Trello looks to heavily rely on dynamically created visual cues. Unless the designers have actively considered non-visual alternatives, I would guess that Trello would be totally unusable. If they had considered this, they would be pretty certain that it would work!

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tested it, but I did find this keyboard command guide, so maybe?
https://trello.com/shortcuts

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts are sure nice, but what's the benefit if you cannot read the contents of the site?